# KDTree Utility in Blender with Python

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, select

I am trying to use the KDTree to find the nearest vertex from a particular point. I am trying to run the sample provided in Blender document - [kdtree](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.kdtree.html).

I have added a Icosphere and trying to find the nearest vertex from origin but its not giving me the correct vertex, it may be something with local/global coordinate

following the sample code -

```
import mathutils
import bpy
# create a kd-tree from a mesh
from bpy import context

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

obj = context.object

mesh = obj.data
size = len(mesh.vertices)
kd = mathutils.kdtree.KDTree(size)

for i, v in enumerate(mesh.vertices):
    kd.insert(v.co, i)

kd.balance()


# Find the closest point to the center
co_find = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
co, index, dist = kd.find(co_find)
print("Close to center:", co, index, dist)


mesh.vertices[index].select = True

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

[image]

Sample blender file : [blender test](https://blend-exchange.com/b/v4pgJDy0/)

Comment: For me it works if i don't move/rotate the object in object mode (so location and rotation still 0 for all), and if i just move and rotate it in edit mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
for i, v in enumerate(mesh.vertices):
    kd.insert(v.co, i)
```

by:

```
for i, v in enumerate(mesh.vertices):
    kd.insert(obj.matrix_world @ v.co, i)
```

So that the coordinates are all in world space.

Or, alternatively, you can set the searched location in local space, by replacing:

```
co_find = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

by:

```
co_find = obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

Comment: nice!...works for me!

Comment: Thanks! worked for me as well....